# AngularJS request model before another model create [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create simple webapp on MEAN stack.

I want to create Offer that belongs to Exposition, but don't know how to request Exposition before call createOffer.

Here is my code

```
$stateProvider
  .state('offer', {
    url: "/exposition/:expId/offer/",
    templateUrl: 'app/exposition/listOffers.tpl.html',
    controller: 'OffersController'
  })
  .state('offercreate', {
    url: "/exposition/:expId/offer/create/",
    templateUrl: 'app/exposition/createOffer.tpl.html',
    controller: 'OffersController'
  })
  .state('offerview', {
    url: "/exposition/:expId/offer/:id/",
    templateUrl: 'app/exposition/detailsOffer.tpl.html',
    controller: 'OffersController'
  });
```

And controller

```
offerApp.controller('OffersController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$state', '$location', 'OfferUpdateService', 'Upload',
    function ($scope, $resource, $state, $location, OfferUpdateService, Upload) {
      var OfferResource = $resource('/offer/:id');
      var ExpositionResource = $resource('/exposition/:id');
      $scope.offerUpdateService = new OfferUpdateService();
      var loadOffers = function () {
        return OfferResource.query(function (results) {
          $scope.offers = results;
          if ($state.params.id) {
            $scope.findOffer($state.params.id);
          }
          if ($state.params.expId) {
            ExpositionResource.findExposition($state.params.expId);
          }
        });
      };
    }
]);
```

Is it correct idea? I want to load Exposition before Offer and then just map exposition.id to Offer model.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific problem? Question is rather vague

Comment: @charlietfl the question is how to load parent model before creating child. ExpositionResource.findExposition($state.params.expId); - this code doesn't work

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not a proper problem description. We don't know if requests are being made, if errors are thrown , what `findOffer()` is or if it fails. Provide better troubleshooting details from dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl  Request are being made. No errors. When OfferResource.query is called it returns only one model - Offer. If I would union it with response of findExposition method, I would get 2 models(objects) in one json object. So, how to deal with it. I am new to angular and node, but I want to understand how to connect two models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a promise chain to do this.  I'm not entirely clear as to how your resource objects work (as I use $q & $http instead, but the docs indicate they return objects with RESTful APIs). Here is an example of requesting 2 resources in sequential order:

```
var OfferResource = $resource('/offer/:id');
var ExpositionResource = $resource('/exposition/:id');
ExpositionResource.get({id:123}).$promise.then( function(rsp, rspHeaders){ 

    //set your model ID how you want
    model.id = rsp.id

    //now hit your next API in the sequence
    OfferResource.query({id:model.id}).$promise.then( function(rsp2, rspHeaders2){
        //you can do this again if need be to a 3rd sequential call
    })
})
```

Comment: Helped me! Thank you!